# How to run applications as root using gksu alternative

Tags: gksu, pkexec

When I run applications like Synaptic or Gparted, I'm prompted by the lovely screen on the left, to enter my admin password. I think this has something to do with `pkexec`.

But when I run applications using `gksu` I am prompted by the ugly window on the right.

I'd like to run Nautilus or Gedit sometimes as root and be prompted by the nicer window on the left.

[image]

Update 2015/4/09 6:00pm

```
$ pkexec gedit
gdk_mir_display_open
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:9664): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Comment: As a matter for AskUbuntu-meta , yes the answer suggested also answers my question but I would never have found that answer if it hadn't been asked the way I asked it.

Comment: @JoshuaRobison Indeed--but now, others searching for this information will find this duplicate question and in doing so find the master question also. [This is why duplicates often have some value and are closed but often not deleted.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions/)